# Access particular element/item in QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

How can we access the element in QtableView? 
The line `self.tableView.item(1,1)` does not sem to work?
It gives error `AttributeError: 'QTableView' object has no attribute 'item'`

How can we access a particular element in QTableView say (3,4)?

Comment: As far as I know there is no item attribute in QTableView. According to [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html) you can only say self.tableView.rowAt(3).columnAt(1)

Comment: @mutantkeyboard self.tableView.rowAt(3).columnAt(1) does not work. AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ColumnAt'

Comment: I didn't see the whole code, and what do you try to select? If you need a visual selection, you can do something like `self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)` . It will select the row that you click. If you target specific cell, use the `QModelIndex indexAt` method

Comment: No its not about selecting the elements its about accessing them. I am trying to get particular element and then test it for its datatype.

Comment: Aha, for that you need a QTableWidgetItem, and then you use it like `self.table.item(3,1).text()`

Comment: you need to provide more detail on how you're using the QTableView, ...ie what "model" you've chosen to hold the data you're adding to the QTableView. QTableView has no direct access to the data, you have to implement a QAbstractItemModel to add the data, and that's where you'll get the accessor methods from. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html : "QTableView implements the interfaces defined by the QAbstractItemView class to allow it to display data provided by models derived from the QAbstractItemModel class."

Comment: @segFaultCoder yeah I am sorry I did not mention it, I did not think it has to do with the "Model". Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you're using a `QStandardItemModel` with the `QTableView`, you can do this:

```
model = self.tableView.model()
item = model.item(1, 1)
```

**EDIT**:

If you want the item's text, you can do:

```
text = item.text()
```

For the other properties of items, see the [QStandardItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html) reference.

Comment: self.model.item(1,1) returns something like the location of the  item (<PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem object at 0x0000000007FAA0D8>
) not the value of the item? is it something slightly different? I am using PyQt4, if that helps!

Comment: @VenkataNarsiReddyVaddula. Yes, it returns the item - which is what you asked for. If you want the item's text, all you need to do is `text = item.text()`.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not do that on purpose.